# How to install additional modules included in a Bower package?

Tags: highcharts, gruntjs, bower

I can't add a module which included in one of the installed packages.

I need to add "bower_components/highcharts-release/modules/funnel.js" to the concatenated scripts.js file.

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
... More bower packages
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>

// Can't add modules/funnel.js as this block is automatically generated.

<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
... App scripts
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/modules/funnel.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This doesn't works, the modules/funnel.js file is not included in the scripts.js minified version.

Where should I add the dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding a new usemin block:

`<!-- build:js(.) scripts/modules.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/highcharts-release/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->`

Answer (score 1):

[grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#what-can-go-wrong) plugin automatically injects files which are present in the main block of your project's bower.json's dependencies bower.json files

Therefore you will need to go to `bower_components/highcharts-release/` folder and add the `modules/funnel.js` file in the `bower.json` main block there

```
"main": [
    "highcharts.js",
    "highcharts-more.js",
    "modules/exporting.js",
    "modules/funnel.js"
]
```